# Python - Plotting a graph from an array where the data in the array is from a data file

Tags: python

OK, Ive got the array from this code

```
data = np.genfromtxt("1.dat", skip_header=16, delimiter='\t', dtype=str)
```

which creates an array of the data, but when i try to plot a graph using "data" it doesnt work, do i need to tell the program which are the x and y componants of the array? i thought putting it in an array automatically gave the x and y coordinates to the columns in the array.

ive tried over and over to plot the data, but it keeps saying it can plot it, im assuming because x and y values have not been defined??

once again any help is appreciated

Comment: Give a small example what the data looks like, the code which you use to start the plot plus the exact error message.

Comment: You have to know the shape of `data` and say to matplotlib (for example) to plot this axis agains another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that data has something in it by verifying data.shape is meaningful.

```
data = random.rand(10,10)

plot(data[:,0],data[:,1])
```

will take the 'x' values to be the first column of data and the 'y' values to be the second column of data.  This plot will likely have crossings as everything is random.

```
plot(data)
```

will take each column in data and plot against the index of the column element (i.e. the row index)

```
plot(data[:,0],data[:,1],data[:,4],data[:,7]) will plot x,y as 0,1 and x,y as 4,7

plot(data[:,0:4]) will plot the first four columns against the row index
```

Similar things could be done with the rows instead.